# using min, max and avg in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table Like below.

I want the product_id of Minimum, Maximum and Average cost products in a single query.

```
CREATE TABLE productlist(product_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                         cost INT);                             

INSERT INTO productlist(cost)
                 VALUES('2450'),
                       ('2200'),
                       ('2580'),
                       ('2405'),
                       ('3500'),
                       ('1500'),
                       ('1800'),
                       ('1520'),
                       ('1740'),
                       ('1940'),
                       ('2940'),
                       ('1250'),
                       ('1290'),
                       ('1390'),
                       ('2900');
```

Output:

```
Min    12
Max    5
Avg    2093
```

I tried like one below but its not working.

```
SELECT product_id, MIN(cost) as mincost
  FROM productlist
 GROUP BY product_id
 ORDER BY mincost ASC
 LIMIT 0,1
 UNION
SELECT product_id, max(cost) as maxcost
  FROM productlist
 GROUP BY product_id
 ORDER BY maxcost DESC
 LIMIT 0,1
```

How should I do this

Comment: the `product_id` is set as `AUTO_INCREMENT` and a `PRIMARY KEY`. getting the min, max, avg *for each* `product_id` doesn't make sense since no `product_Id` is the same.

Comment: I need to display the maximum and minimum product cost in table.The only way is to write separate query?

Comment: What is the product id of avg ? if Avg = 2093, mysql AVG function won't return you the ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 'Min', product_id 
from productlist
where cost = (select min(cost) from productlist)
UNION 
select 'Max', product_id
from productlist
where cost = (select MAX(cost) from productlist)
UNION 
select 'Avg', round(AVG(cost),0) as Avg
from productlist
```

Comment: No it will never return product id Avg is common for all See the op in question

Answer (score 1):

```
select product_id, cost
from productlist where cost = (SELECT max(cost)from productlist)
union
select product_id, cost
from productlist where cost = (SELECT min(cost)from productlist)
union
select product_id, cost
from productlist where cost = (SELECT x.cost from productlist x, productlist y
GROUP BY x.cost
HAVING SUM(SIGN(1-SIGN(y.cost-x.cost))) = (COUNT(*)+1)/2)
```

This uses median, returns product id in every case

Comment: Wow. Gr8 I Just Checked your solution Really Nice one It brings the nearest product_Id to average if i am Right.

Comment: its uses median : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median, which is different to mean, or mode. They are all types of "average".

Answer (score 1):

the output you want is not coming by the query you wrote
you need to try out this one for getting the required output

```
select 'Min', product_id 
from productlist
where cost = (select min(cost) from productlist)
UNION 
select 'Max', product_id
from productlist
where cost = (select MAX(cost) from productlist)
UNION 
select 'Avg', floor(AVG(cost)) as Avg
from productlist
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to select all the products

```
  SELECT 
          max(cost), MIN(cost), AVG(cost)
    FROM 
          productlist
    GROUP BY
          product_id
```

GROUP BY is not exactly required here. But seems like you are beginner, googling to will help you.

For your question try this.

```
SELECT 
          (select CONCAT(product_id, '-', cost) from  productlist group by product_id order by cost DESC limit 1) as MAX,
          (select CONCAT(product_id, '-', cost) from  productlist group by product_id order by cost ASC limit 1) as MIN,
          (select avg(cost) from  productlist) as AVG
FROM 
           productlist limit 1
```

Comment: Not only is GROUP BY not required, it's __wrong__. It will just report the cost of each product, not the min/max/average of all products.

Comment: Try now. I have added one more query

Answer (score 0):

This answers your question exactly but it should be noted that it costs 3 table scans to find this data. Also, the example in the question suggests that the average value is [truncated](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate) down to 2093 from 2093.67. It is perhaps better to replace this with [round](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb224/30)

```
SELECT concat('Min ', product_id) 
  FROM productlist
 WHERE cost = (SELECT min(cost) from productlist)
UNION ALL
SELECT concat('Max ', product_id) 
  FROM productlist
 WHERE cost = (SELECT max(cost) from productlist)
UNION ALL
SELECT concat('Avg ', truncate(avg(cost), 0)) 
  FROM productlist
```

Comment: it doesn't return product id

Comment: That wasn't in the example output so it isn't in mine. I'll added it but generally I would say that it's a good idea to include it in the question if you want it in the answer :)